# Multiple controllers per request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, httprequest, spring-roo

It is possible to use multiple controllers to handle a single request. There would still be a main controller that the request is going to process. This main controller would then be rendered on the `body` tile attribute. The other controllers are used to render (`menu`, `header`, `footer`) tile attribute.

In short would this `layout.xml` possibly correct?

```
<definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx">
   <put-attribute name="header" value="/other/header" />
   <put-attribute name="menu" value="/other/menu" />
   <put-attribute name="footer" value="/other/footer" />
</definition>
```

In which `/other/**` is mapped using the code structure of `OtherController`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/other/**")
public class OtherController {

    @RequestMapping(value="header") 
    public String header() { 
        // TODO Statements here
        return "other/header";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="menu") 
    public String menu() { 
        // TODO Statements here
        return "other/menu";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="footer") 
    public String footer() { 
        // TODO Statements here
        return "other/footer";
    }

}
```

Comment: why you need multiple controller for that? you can do that in tiles configuration file.

Comment: Well I may need some data from the DB which can be processed by a controller (for statistics). If I'm going to use scriptlets, it might cause injection problems since the service isn't annotated with `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 0):

No, multiple Controllers cannot manage the same request.

This is not a Roo issue, it is about Spring MVC. When a request comes the request dispatcher search for the Controller that match the request path, url, etc and delegates on it to handle the request.

The dispatcher delegates on the 1st Controller that match with request path, params, etc, so if you have more than one Controller registered for the same request only the 1st found will handle the request.

Comment: AFAIK it's not even possible to have ambiguous requests mappings. Spring won't start with an error message.